# Calculating requests per second, per IP address on NGINX

Tags: nginx, throttling

I need to implement NGINX rate limiting. There's plenty of guides out there on how to do this, but no guides on how to get real values/stats from the access logs.

What I need to get from the NGINX access logs is.

1. Requests per minute, per IP address
2. Average requests per minute, derived from all IP addresses
3. Max requests per minute, per IP address

Is this even possible? A Senior Engineer here tells me it's not, I think it may be though, but I'm a bit of a Linux noob.

Thanks guys